# Do all USB cables have power lines?

Tags: power-supply, usb, cables

I have a USB type A to type B cable, I took it from a printer. Now, I want to utilize this USB cable to make a 5V breadboard power supply. I will cut the cable and connect power lines to breadboard's power rails. But, I can't be sure if it is guaranteed to have cables for power transmission or not. I mean, I don't want to ruin the cable if it cannot be used to transmit power.

So, I am sure (well, almost) that there are data lines in the cable, because it was used to transfer data between computer and printer. However, printer had its own power plug. Thus, I am not sure whether this cable has a power line or just data lines.

Comment: All USB cables have power lines.

Comment: @DKNguyen ok, thank you.

Comment: no, they do not ... i am 99% certain that at least one cable exists that does not have all of the wires ... think about it, someone somewhere has manufactured a cheap cable

Comment: Some dirt-cheap charging cables have only the power line (which is **not USB-compliant**).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the USB connector on the cable is stamped/embossed with the USB logotype, then it has all four wires connected.

Comment: I just realized that looking into the connectors and counting the goldish parts could give information about cable count....

Comment: @muyustan No, the connector will surely have all the pins, but the cable may still lack one wire.

Comment: well, I just realized something and it turned out to be wrong..........

Comment: Anecdote: We have seen all kinds of craziness when dicing up 'standard' cables.  Certainly not all USB cables have the same gauge wire - at least that's typically in the datasheet.  Historically, the greatest offender for conductor unpredictability from manufacturer-to-manufacturer were cable assemblies with D-shaped, 9-pin connectors ("DB9's").

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen My boss has an anecdote where they ordered a large number of bog standard USB cables from a company in china, but turns out a lot of them failed. They manufactured X-ray machines so they X-rayed some cables and some of them had wires that didn't reach the connector etc. The manufacturer shrugged and just said that if you wanted them all to _work_ you should have specified that in the order.

Answer (score 5):

A USB-compliant device must sense VBUS voltage level regardless whether they use their local power or not, see [details here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/323551/117785). Therefore every standard USB cable does have the VBUS and Ground wires.

An exception is a special USB 3.0 cable used/defined for Windows Debugger over USB port, it has  Type-A to Type-A plugs on both ends (non-standard for USB), usually of orange color, and no VBUS connection.

Comment: That's the information I was looking for but didn't find. When I did not found anything about VBUS I had to assume that a device could pull-up to its own power.

Comment: USB-A/male to USB-A/male cables are part of the USB standard but they are uncommon.  Part of the standard is to not have the Vbus and D+/D- lines connected.  This is one exception where Vbus is not part of the handshake process.